# Rellenar una tabla con js usando fetch

Tags: javascript

Buenas me estoy inciando en js y no logro introducir datos en una tabla usando js me podrían ayudar quiero que un bbucle recorra un array donde guardo los datos sacado del fetch y me los vaya introduciendo uno a uno en la tabla, muchas gracias.

/*Aqui empiza el javascript*/

```
let lista1 = document.getElementById("th");
let lista2 = document.getElementById("td");
let lista3 = document.getElementById("tr");

let arrayCapitales = Array();

function setArrayCapitales(capitales) {

    for (let cap of capitales) {
        arrayCapitales.push(cap.capital[0]);
    }

    for (const capital of arrayCapitales) {
        let listItem = document.createElement('th');
        listItem.innerHTML = "<p>" + capital + "</p>";
        listCap.appendChild(listItem);
    }
}

/*Aquí el flecth donde hacemos la petición de las ciudades*/

fetch('https://restcountries.com/v3.1/region/europe')
    .then(response => {
        if (response.ok) {
            console.log("Respuesta OK");
            return response.json();
        }
    })
    .then(capitales => {
        console.log(capitales);

        setSelectArrayCapitales(capitales);
    })
    .catch(
        (error) => { console.log(error) }
    )
```

---

```
Este es el html.
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="assents\js\fetch2.js"></script>

</head>
<style>
    table {
        display: flex;
        padding: 20px;
        text-align: center;
        justify-content: center;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        padding: 50px;
    }

    td,
    th {
        border: 3px solid black;
        padding: 8px;
    }

    th {

        width: 180px;
    }
</style>

<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>

    </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Con este codigo puedes generar la tabla dinamicamente con los datos recogidos de la peticion, para acceder a un array de objetos que hay dentro del propio array puedes hacer lo mismo.

```
fetch('https://restcountries.com/v3.1/region/europe')
.then(response => response.json())
.then(data => {

var tabla = document.createElement('table');

// por cada dato se crea una fila
for (const fila of data){
    let tr = document.createElement('tr');

    // otro bucle para recorrer los datos de cada objeto
    for (const atributo of Object.values(fila)) {

        var celda = document.createElement('td');
        celda.textContent = atributo;
        celda.style.border = '1px solid';
        tr.appendChild(celda);
    }

    tr.appendChild(celda);

    tabla.appendChild(tr);
}
document.body.appendChild(tabla);
})
```